# Binance Chain API - How to query Cross-chain transactions (BSC to BC)

Tags: binance, binance-smart-chain, binance-api-client, binance-chain

I am interested in seeing all of the transactions that take place on a Binance Chain BNB address (bnb1...)

I see that I can use this API to get most of the transactions that have taken place:
https://dex.binance.org/api/v1/transactions?address=

But one kind of transaction is left out. If I swap BNB from Binance Chain to Binance Smart Chain (BC to BSC) on TrustWallet, say, the transaction shows up as a "Crosschain transfer out", accounting for the coins leaving. But if I swap BNB from BSC to BC, the transaction does not show up at all. I was expecting something like a "Crosschain transfer in" to account for the BNB coin coming in.

Is there a good way to query for these sorts of BSC to BC transactions?

My current solution is to query all of the transactions in the 11 addresses that perform transactions of type "Oracle Claim", taken from here (https://github.com/binance-chain/node-binary/blob/master/fullnode/prod/0.5.8/config/genesis.json) :

bnb1kdx4xkktr35j2mpxncvtsshswj5gq577me7lx4 (Aconcagua)
bnb1slq53dua0nj3e6y949u4yc3erus0t68k37jcwh (Ararat)
bnb139l5umk42mam3znr568gw706fwvp485kw5zks3 (Carrauntoohil)
(etc...)
And searching each transaction's data to see if any involve my address.

However, there are a large number of transactions to search through, so this seems unfeasible. I am guessing there is a better way?